# Как запустить gif анимацию в objective-c?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Сделала Gifку, но как ее запустить? Все перерыла, не нашла. Помогите, пожалуйста..

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, помогут эти 2 ссылки:

- [Animated-GIF-iPhone](https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone)
- [uiimage-from-animated-gif](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/)

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без Gif. 
[Код.](http://www.imaladec.com/upload-files/Source/Examples/animations/ImageAnimator.zip)